# How to print a C BSTR in Excel 16 for Mac with VBA?

Tags: c, macos, vba, excel

I have a C function which returns a BSTR like "Hello world" and in Excel 11 I can call this function to print the string with the msgbox vba function.
With Excel 16, I only have an returned empty string.
If I am in debug with XCode, I can see my BSTR and it is not empty.

Do you have any idea to get a BSTR, returned by a C function, with the VBA of Excel 16?

Comment: Could you give to me the implementation of a function pls ? Because I have the opposite problem : under mac os x + excel's 2011 VBA, I want to design a c++ (or even c) function in a dll that will be able to receive string's from VBA (where strings are in fact BSTR's...) THx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used SysAllocString but this function return NULL pointer. To fix my problem, I need to create my BSTR byte by byte